# Check if input is textbox, select, textarea or radio

Tags: jquery

I have a form with different html input fields...

```
1) <input type="text">
2) <textarea></textarea> 
3) <input type="checkbox">
4) <input type="radio">
5) <select></select>
```

How would I be able to determine what type of input field it is using jQuery. *For example: If I wanted to do a check to see if input = "select" then do stuff.*

Comment: i think you can use `each()` to loop around your form and do some conditions inside of it.

Comment: Ya Im doing that but I need to check what input type it is or if select or radio or textarea

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('input') // selects all types of inputs
$('input:checkbox') // selects checkboxes
$('select') // selects select element
$('input:radio') // selects radio inputs
$('input[type="text"]') // selects text inputs
```

you can use `event.target.type`, this alerts what type of `input`, `textrea` or `select` is the target of the event.

```
$('input, textarea, select').change(function(event){
   alert(event.target.type)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4BNH/

Comment: Whilst this is the correct way of selecting specific form fields, I think the OP wants to *test* whether an element is a specific field; not to select it.

Comment: +1 now. The best answer as it returns the type of object; without the comparison required by .is().

Comment: Sebastian's answer below returns what kind of input a $ element is (albeit you now need to use `.prop("type")` instead of `.attr("type")`

Answer (score 15):

You can use jquery's .is().  For example

```
  if ( $(this).is("input") )   //or 
  if ( $(this).is('input:text') )
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all the form elements using `:input` as selector. Since `select` and `textarea` elements do not have a `type` attribute, you want to use `.is()`

```
   $(':input').each(function(){
       if($(this).is('select')){
          var inputType = 'select';
       }else if($(this).is('input:text')){
          var inputType = 'text';
       }else if($(this).is('input:checkbox')){
          var inputType = 'checkbox';
       }
       console.log('input type = '+inputType+');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For 1, 3, 4:

```
$("input").attr('type');
```

Comment: It gives me undefined for select option

Comment: select and text area are not input types, they are stand alone DOM elements.

Comment: you may have to use `.prop('type')` to get a value - seems jQ is separating the use of attr() vs prop()

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use JQuery is syntax

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Something along the lines of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var items = $("input");
    if(items.first().is("input[type=text]")) {
     alert("Text type");            
    }
});
```

You can check it out here
http://jsfiddle.net/JRLn9/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var tipo = $('#elemento14').attr('type');
```

Comment: `var tipo = $('#elemento14').prop('type');` jQ yields the type with prop(), but "undefined" with attr(). jQ seems to be abandoning attr().

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing a selector that will pull out each of these elements, and then you can iterate through them and check the type. Something like this:

```
$('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if(el.is('input')) { //we are dealing with an input
        var type = el.attr('type'); //will either be 'text', 'radio', or 'checkbox
    } else if(el.is('select')) { //we are dealing with a select
        //code here
    } else { //we are dealing with a textarea
        //code here
    }
});
```