# how can i make key value pair for label and value label : value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i want to make table with `label` and `value` pair,  suppose i have something like this  `<label>i can </label>` and `value`  like this `<input type="text" value="why not" />`  **my desired result**
  `{"i can" : " why not "}`

here is my sample element with code snippet

```js
var result = [];

$('div label').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
   var label = $this.text();
   //console.log(label);
   
   value = $this.siblings().attr('value');
   //console.log(value);
  
    result.push({label:label,value:value});
});


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="uploaddata.php" method="POST">

<div class="form-group">
        <label for="text-1483332101835-preview" class="fb-text-label">Mobile Number :  </label> 

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobNum" value="963242726" id="mobNum">
</div>

<div class="form-group">

      <label for="textarea" class="fb-textarea-label" >Comments :  </label>

      <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" name="comments" maxlength="11" id="comments">
          very bad service
      </textarea>

</div>


<div class="form-group">

<label for="select" class="fb-select-label">Select Your Locality:  </label>

    <select type="select" class="form-control" name="locality" id="locality">
              <option value="vrpura">V.R Pura</option><option selected="true" value="bel">B.E.L</option>
              <option value="jala">Jalahalli</option>

      </select> 
  </div>
  
  
 <div class="fb-checkbox form-group field-checkbox-1483332316174-preview">

        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox-1483332316174-preview" id="checkbox-1483332316174-preview"> 

        <label for="checkbox-1483332316174-preview" class="fb-checkbox-label">Home Delivery:  </label>
  
 </div>
  
  
  <div class="fb-checkbox form-group field-checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview">
  
  
  <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview" class="fb-checkbox-group-label">Select Your Item :  </label>
  
  
 <div class="checkbox-group">
                      <input value="jamoon" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name=""                                         id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-0" checked="">
                      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-0">Jamoon</label><br>
                      
                      <input value="samosa" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview[]"                                   id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-1" selected=""> 
                      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-1">samosa</label><br>
                      
                      
                      <input value="beedi" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview[]"                                id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-2" selected=""> 
                      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-2">beedi</label><br>
  
  
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Please note** for `check group`  i want all the `checked value`  with single `label` and all its associated `checked values`.

and for `select` i want single `selected value`  how it can be done?

please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what is working and what not ?

Comment: @YoYo, `check group`  and `textarea` format i don't know

Comment: why would you want a whole bunch of objects with different property names in each object in the first place? What's wrong with current format with consistent property names? This sounds like an XY problem

Answer (score 1):

However as per OP statement, You need to create a object then set it property

```
var obj = {};
obj[label] = value;
result.push(obj);
```

```js
var result = [];

$('div label').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var label = $this.text();
  value = $this.siblings().attr('value');

  var obj = {};
  obj[label] = value;
  result.push(obj);
});


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="uploaddata.php" method="POST">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text-1483332101835-preview" class="fb-text-label">Mobile Number :</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobNum" value="963242726" id="mobNum">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="textarea-1483332158183-preview" class="fb-textarea-label">Comments :</label>

    <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" name="comments" maxlength="11" id="comments">
      very bad service
    </textarea>

  </div>


  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="select-1483332201030-preview" class="fb-select-label">Select Your Locality:</label>

    <select type="select" class="form-control" name="locality" id="locality">
      <option value="vrpura">V.R Pura</option>
      <option selected="true" value="bel">B.E.L</option>
      <option value="jala">Jalahalli</option>

    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="fb-checkbox form-group field-checkbox-1483332316174-preview">

    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox-1483332316174-preview" id="checkbox-1483332316174-preview">

    <label for="checkbox-1483332316174-preview" class="fb-checkbox-label">Home Delivery:</label>

  </div>


  <div class="fb-checkbox form-group field-checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview">


    <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview" class="fb-checkbox-group-label">Select Your Item :</label>


    <div class="checkbox-group">
      <input value="jamoon" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="" id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-0" checked="">
      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-0">Jamoon</label>
      <br>

      <input value="samosa" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview[]" id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-1" selected="">
      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-1">samosa</label>
      <br>


      <input value="beedi" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview[]" id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-2" selected="">
      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-2">beedi</label>
      <br>


    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

I would recommend you to use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

> Encode a set of form elements as an array of names and values.

```js
console.log($("form").serializeArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="uploaddata.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text-1483332101835-preview" class="fb-text-label">Mobile Number :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobNum" value="963242726" id="mobNum">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textarea-1483332158183-preview" class="fb-textarea-label">Comments :</label>
    <textarea type="textarea" class="form-control" name="comments" maxlength="11" id="comments">
      very bad service
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="select-1483332201030-preview" class="fb-select-label">Select Your Locality:</label>
    <select type="select" class="form-control" name="locality" id="locality">
      <option value="vrpura">V.R Pura</option>
      <option selected="true" value="bel">B.E.L</option>
      <option value="jala">Jalahalli</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="fb-checkbox form-group field-checkbox-1483332316174-preview">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox-1483332316174-preview" id="checkbox-1483332316174-preview">
    <label for="checkbox-1483332316174-preview" class="fb-checkbox-label">Home Delivery:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="fb-checkbox form-group field-checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview">
    <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview" class="fb-checkbox-group-label">Select Your Item :</label>
    <div class="checkbox-group">
      <input value="jamoon" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview[]" id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-0" checked="">
      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-0">Jamoon</label>
      <br>
      <input value="samosa" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview[]" id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-1" checked="">
      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-1">samosa</label>
      <br>
      <input value="beedi" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-group" name="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview[]" id="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-2" checked="">
      <label for="checkbox-group-1483332396337-preview-2">beedi</label>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but one request i have can you make `check group` with single `label` and `an` `array` of `checked` `value`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop in label and inputs the way you doing or as said by Satpal you can use map and [serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) too
Now if you dont use serializeArray then you have to check what type of input label has then only you can get the selected text or values

*For Eg:*

*If next is `checkbox` then following checks has to be done to get value,*

```
if($(this).next().is(":checkbox")){

        $.each($(this).siblings(":checked"), function(){            
            alert($(this).val());

           // get all checked values
        });

}
```

You can go through [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215598/check-if-input-is-textbox-select-textarea-or-radio) to know more. So better to go with [**serializeArray**](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

Comment: `val()` on `<select>` returns same as val() on selected option and you are missing a `find()` for option

Comment: it is fine for `select` but can you show me any way for `check group` selected `value` thanks in advance

Comment: @charlietfl : Oh yes . Just wanted to make  a point . But for radio buttons and checkboxes I dont think you can get using sameas you said

Comment: no...but neither would they match `is('select')` which is the only other case you covered

Comment: @DilipG : check the answer I updated for checkboxes. But  again I am saying use serializeArray . It will automatically create an array. you just have to give a name to all inputs . read about serializeArray